# how to send JSON post data to server by using ItemClickListener

Tags: android, json

I'm doing a project about JSON  receive and send post data. I succeed receiving data using listView but i don't know how to send the "name" to the server. 
Here's my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;


import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import learn2crack.asynctask.library.JSONParser;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ListView list;
    TextView ver;
    TextView name;
    TextView api;
    Button Btngetdata;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    //URL to get JSON Array
    private static String url = "http://api.learn2crack.com/android/jsonos/";
    private static String purl = ""; // the server hasn't ready yet 

    //JSON Node Names 
    private static final String TAG_OS = "android";
    private static final String TAG_VER = "ver";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_API = "api";

    JSONArray android = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        Btngetdata = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getdata);
        Btngetdata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                 new JSONParse().execute();

            }
        });

    }

    private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
         private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
             ver = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.vers);
             name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
             api = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.api);
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            // Getting JSON from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            return json;
        }
         @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
             pDialog.dismiss();
             try {
                    // Getting JSON Array from URL
                    android = json.getJSONArray(TAG_OS);
                    for(int i = 0; i < android.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject c = android.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                    String ver = c.getString(TAG_VER);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String api = c.getString(TAG_API);

                    // Adding value HashMap key => value

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    map.put(TAG_VER, ver);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    map.put(TAG_API, api);

                    oslist.add(map);
                    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, oslist,
                            R.layout.list_item,
                            new String[] { TAG_VER,TAG_NAME, TAG_API }, new int[] {
                                    R.id.vers,R.id.name, R.id.api});

                    list.setAdapter(adapter);

                    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                int position, long id) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at "+oslist.get(+position).get("name"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            //send "name" to the (purl)


                        }
                    });


                    }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

         }
    }

}
```

If can. I also wish to limit the ItemClickListener not more than 3 times, something like this :

```
while (list.setOnItemClickListener<3){
}
```

i tried this method 
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

```
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                            int position, long id) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at "+oslist.get(+position).get("name"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        //testing 1 start
                        //the year data to send
                        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        String sname = oslist.get(+position).get("name");
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name",sname));

                        //http post
                        try{
                                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(purl);
                                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                                is = entity.getContent();

                        }catch(Exception e){
                                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
                        }

                        //testing end

                    }
                });
```

because of my partner's server hasn't ready i cant test this can really work or not. 
Please help me with this problem and thanks for very one work answered my question.

Comment: it surprises me , u are doing a ui operation in the async task, and u dnt get any errors ??

Comment: it works fine for me .. I'm using my SAMSUNG note2 .. I previously I'm doing ui operation on bundle and have some network problem

Answer (score 0):

Use http post method to post your json data with namevaluepair method and if you want to prevent click listener not more than 3 times you have to maintain own variable and check if less than or equal 3 times then do your stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using httppost request and stringEntity to send JSON data.

Replace your doInBackground code to this:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpUriRequest request;
try {


        request = new HttpPost(url);


            StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(<-JSON DATA->);//{"name":"Yourname"}
            ((HttpPost) request).setEntity(entity);


        ((HttpPost) request).setHeader("Content-Type",
                "application/json");

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    String json = convertStreamToString(entity.getContent());

    return new JSONObject(json) ;
} catch (Exception e) {

}
```

Comment: thanks for the tip, but i had include my JSONParser class. Will I able to receive data after removed it ?? @vipulmittal

Comment: should i do anything on PostExecute ??

Comment: You can keep doing whatever you were doing in post execute just change do in background code to this